# eclipse return exit code = 13

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I tried to install the Eclipse Standard 4.4. I downloaded it and extracted it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse`. When I first tried to launch it, it said like this:
[image]

Then I copy the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\bin\javaw` into the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse`.

Then, I tried to launch the eclipse again. Now this came out:
[image]

I checked online for the solution but I still cannot solve it. I am a beginner and I found I cannot understand most of the solution. Is there any easy way to solve this problem. Thanks ahead for you advice :-)

Comment: Pretty sure you installed Java wrong. You're going to need to download and install the Java Software Development Kit (JDK), not just a JRE. Read the instructions. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp

Comment: exit code = 13 - permissions ?

Comment: Eclipse does not need a full JDK, although it can use one. It needs only a JRE.

Comment: You have a 64 bit Eclipse and a 32 bit Java - they must be both 64 bit or both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

First go to this link and [and download jdk here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp) as the warning says you need it.